# search with ngram in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I can search terms in Elasticsearch 
Btw, I set up setting as follows:

```
.startObject("filter")
    .startObject("lowercase")
         .field("type", "lowercase")
    .endObject()
.endObject()
.startObject("filter")
    .startObject("ngram")
        .field("type", "nGram")
        .field("min_gram", "3")
        .field("max_gram", "10")
    .endObject()
.endObject()
```

And then I tried to map this like this.

```
builder.startObject().startObject(TYPE_TEST).startObject("properties");
   builder.startObject(title)
            .field("type", "string")
            .field("store", "yes")
            .field("analyzer", "series_analyzer")
            .field("boost", "10")
   .endObject();
```

And then I search for "terms" in entire field like this.

```
 curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search?q="testte"
```

I cannot find any result with query, "some partial terms".

Instead, I can get good result with this query

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search?q=title:testte
```

I just want to search terms with nGram without 'title' field. How can I search terms in entire field?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have back partial matches obtained via ngrams only if you search on the field that you indexed using ngrams. In your case it's the `title` field defined in your mapping. When you don't specify a field in your [query_string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/), it uses by default the `_all` field, which is indexed using the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer/). You can either specify a different default field in your query, so that you can avoid to specify it for each term. If you want to apply ngrams to all your fields you could change the mapping for the `_all` fields, but I wouldn't suggest to do so.
Ngrams tend to considerably increase the size of your index, thus I wouldn't apply them everywhere. Also, it's usually better to apply a different text analysis to each field (or group of fields), which is usually domain driven.

Furthermore, the `_all` field is really handy when it comes to getting started and search on everything, but it's the same text analysis applied to all the fields, something you might not want to rely on in production. I would rather suggest to disable it on the long run.

Another hint: have a look at the [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/), which is the query to use in most of the cases. The query_string gives you more power, but it is error prone at the same time. I would use the match query unless you need features that only the query_string provides.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I can solve this problem with multiMatchQuery. Thanks.